# (Windows) hardware discovery for network card with multiple adapters varies

Tags: windows, networking

I have a network card with 4 adapters (Intel server adapter I350-T4). When I insert this card into a PC, the adapters are discovered e.g. as follows:

- I350-T4    => adapter 1
- I350-T4 #2 => adapter 2
- I350-T4 #3 => adapter 3
- I350-T4 #4 => adapter 4

When I get another PC, and another network card (same make and model of course), Windows iterates the devices as follows:

- I350-T4 #4 => adapter 1
- I350-T4 #1 => adapter 2
- I350-T4 #2 => adapter 3
- I350-T4 #3 => adapter 4

This is a problem, as our technical documentation dictates which device is connected to which physical adapter. Since my software only has a reference to the "adapter name" windows assigns to the physical adapter I have no way of guaranteeing which "logical adapter" matches to which physical adapter.

I don't know how windows enumerates the devices on such a network card, and if there are network cards that do have a reproducing way of discovery.

I did test to swap the network cards between the PCs, and found that the way the adapters are discovered **follows** the network card.

Question1: how does windows discover network cards?

Question2: Is there anyway to influence this behavior?

Question3: Is there any logical property (thus in windows) to determine the physical port / position of the adapter?

Question4: If anybody would've experience with this specific topic, is there a better approach that let me couple logical adapters to physical adapters?

Comment: While I don't know the exact details, I expect the order of enumeration is out of Windows' control. The process is probably controlled by the adapter's driver.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37427.identify-physical-port-in-multiple-ports-network-adapter-on-windows-servers-with-powershell.aspx) article

```
Get-NetAdapterHardwareInfo | select Name, InterfaceDescription, DeviceType, Busnumber, Devicenumber, Functionnumber | FL
```

> ```
> Name (This is what you see in Control Panel > .. > Network Connections)
> InterfaceDescription (This is what you see in Device Manager)
> DeviceType (This is connector type of the NIC)
> Busnumber (This is where the NIC is slot on motherboard)
> Devicenumber (This is the location number of slot on motherboard)
> Functionnumber (This is what you are looking for. Physical port)
> ```